# How S3 storage cost works on daily basis?

Tags: amazon-s3

I’ having hard time to calculate S3 storage cost. The case is that I need to store daily backups to it.

The scenario: Let's say that I lease S3 service on 1st of January and send to it 10 files (zip) 10GB each. Then, every single day the 2 oldest files will be deleted and replaced by 2 new ones (10 GB each). So, every day will always stored 100GB of files.

How do I calculate the storage cost in this case? What will i pay at the end of January?

Comment: Stackoverflow is probably a wrong place for such question.

Answer (score 2):

> Objects that are deleted, overwritten, or transitioned to a different storage class before 30 days incur a pro-rated charge equal to the storage charge for the remaining days.

That means that if you store 100 GB for the whole month (say, 30 days), you pay $*N*, but if store 100 GB for 1 day, you pay $(*N*/30).

At the end of the month, you will also pay for outbound traffic (should be minimal in your scenario) and requests made to S3 service (also almost non-existing in your case).

Comment: That means that I'll pay $2.23 per mont approximately?(http://www.cloudberrylab.com/amazon-s3-pricing-explained.aspx)

Comment: Yes. The exact price depends on the region where you create the bucket. On the side note: maybe you should not delete your files right away, but transition them into Glacier storage. It's ultracheap: https://aws.amazon.com/glacier/pricing/. And transitioning can be done automatically with S3 bucket lifecycle policies.

Comment: @SergeyKovalev your quote (from [here](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/)) lacks a citation, and is also partially inaccurate or not applicable to the rest of your answer.  This minimum charge where you pay for an entire month if you delete the object sooner is worth mentioning, but it applies only to the Standard - Infrequent Access (`STANDARD_IA`) storage class, not to Standard or Reduced Redundancy storage.